# RxJava2 onNext can't execute after FlowableEmitter.onNext executed many times

Tags: android, rx-java2

I called the `Flowable.create` to implement that loop read data from bluetooth sockete InputStream, I try the below pseudocode to implement this.

```
// connectBluetoothFlowable is a Flowable<Boolean>
connectBluetoothFlowable.flatMap(bluetoothConnected -> {
    if (!bluetoothConnected) {
        return Flowable.error(new Exception("ERROR"));
    }

    return Flowable.create(emitter -> {
        while(true) {
        // read data from bluetooth sockete InputStream
        // String data = ...;

        // emit the data
        Log.e("emitter", data);
        emitter.onNext(data);

        // if(...) {
        //     break;
        // }
        }

        emitter.onComplete();
    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(data -> {
    // onNext callback
    Log.e("result", "result: " + data);
}, throwable -> {
    // onError
}, () -> {
    // onComplete
}, subscription -> {
    // onSubscribe
});
```

But after `Log.e("emitter", "emitter data");` log many times, the `Log.e("result", "result: " + data);` can't log anymore at onNext callback. I'm so confused why. Could anyone help me?

The RxJava2 version is `2.2.19`, the RxAndroid version is `2.1.1`

I try the below code, but after Log.e("emitter", "emitter data"); log many times, the Log.e("result", "result: " + data); can't log anymore at onNext callback.

```
// connectBluetoothFlowable is a Flowable<Boolean>
connectBluetoothFlowable.flatMap(bluetoothConnected -> {
    if (!bluetoothConnected) {
        return Flowable.error(new Exception("ERROR"));
    }

    return Flowable.create(emitter -> {
        while(true) {
        // read data from bluetooth sockete InputStream
        // String data = ...;

        // emit the data
        Log.e("emitter", data);
        emitter.onNext(data);

        // if(...) {
        //     break;
        // }
        }

        emitter.onComplete();
    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER).onBackpressureBuffer();
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(data -> {
    // onNext callback
    Log.e("result", "result: " + data);
}, throwable -> {
    // onError
}, () -> {
    // onComplete
}, subscription -> {
    // onSubscribe
});
```

Comment: Afaik, chatty loggers or repeatedly logging the same thing is suppressed by Android Studio and/or the runtime you have.

Comment: @akarnokd Yeap, but the log that before emit data still log loop, and when i use `textView.setText(data);` to replace the log in onNext callback, the data cann't change(in fact, the emit data would change in every loop). And when i use breakpoint to debug it, I found that the onNext callback cann't stop at the breakpoint.

Comment: I don't understand your sentences. Where did you put the breakpoint? How spammy is your emitter.onNext ?

Comment: @akarnokd In a word, what i mean is that `Log.e("emitter", data);` would log continuously, but the `Log.e("result", "result: " + data);` would stop log after a period of time. The emitter.onNext is called every 100 milliseconds. Maybe you could ignore the information that I said about the breakpoint.

Comment: In that case, no idea. Try removing `.onBackpressureBuffer()` as it is redundant at best.